# ReactNative TextInput changes fetching data not dinamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My search fetch is working good when I call it in `<Button>` `onPress`, but here calling fetch while typing text is not working completely. For example when I type **app** I see result of **apr**icot and **app**le. Third character change (ap**p**) triggers fetch second time, not third and it results in displaying result of not **app** input but of input **ap**.

```
searchChange = text => {
  this.setState({
    search: text,
  })
};


<TextInput
   placeholder="Food name or description..."
   returnKeyType="search"
   style={styles.textInput}
   onRef={r => {
     this.search = r;
   }}
   onChangeText={this.searchChange}
   onTextInput={() => { this.fetchData(search) }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you change onChangeText to:
onChangeText={()=>this.searchChange()}